# Specifying iterator value in stable_sort function

Tags: c++11, stable-sort

I am using the below code to sort rectangles. 
In the stable_sort function, how can I specify the iterator values other than boundRect.begin and boundRect.end. I want to sort the elements between index 5 to 10. How can I specify these in the stable_sort function? Please guide me.

```
stable_sort( boundRect.begin(), boundRect.end(), compareX_rect );
bool compareX_rect(const Rect & a, const Rect &b) {
    return a.x <= b.x;
}
```

Comment: `stable_sort( boundRect.begin() + 5,  boundRect.begin() + 10, compareX_rect );`?

Comment: Use of `<=` for a comparator results in undefined behavior.  This operator fails the *strict* test defined in [alg.sorting]/p4: The term *strict* refers to the requirement of an irreflexive relation (`!comp(x, x) for all x`).  This operator also reduces the `equiv(a, b)` relationship defined in the same paragraph to `equiv(a, b) == false`.  A hang or a crash is a likely result of using this comparator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `stable_sort` requires random access iterators, you can do simple addition on the iterators:

```
stable_sort(boundRect.begin()+5, boundRect.begin()+10, /* ... */
```

Unless you're dealing with an ancient (pre-C++11) compiler, you can use a lambda expression for the comparison as well:

```
stable_sort(boundRect.begin()+5, boundRect.begin()+10, 
    [](const Rect & a, const Rect &b) { return a.x < b.x; });
```

This not only shorter and easier to read, but will often be faster as well (not that it's likely to matter when you're only sorting 5 elements).